# anything better than webmin?

Tags: server, webmin, nas

Is there any better web based administration tool than webmin?

Or do you recommend learning setting up everything via ssh? I know my way around terminal, but administering a box seems to complex of a task. Is it worth putting time into learning webmin instead of pure terminal? (for the future?)

I don't want to be a sysadmin, but I'd like to learn few things or two...

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of people like Ebox. It's in the repositories. They've changed the name to Zentyal, or perhaps that's a complete server with OS. In any case, you can have a look at it: http://www.zentyal.org/

It's very modular and seems very easy to use. Of course, products like that usually don't do much other than edit text files, so you could do it with an editor. Things like LDAP can be a little more complicated, though.

Answer (score 0):

their site was down. The published install info was incomplete and in some cases files had wrong names.

The zpanel x software was working great on windows never go to try it out on linux cause zpanel was offline? not to mention a jerk or 2 but there are a couple of people like caffein addict who is pretty good at pr he was willing to install for me for free but i was a tad bit pissed at how i was being treated by 1 of the other members. If the site is back up and they have changed or rewrote the installation instructions then I say go ahead it's a great panel and its easy to install even the scripts are easy to install!

But beware on my attempt to install on ubuntu 12.04 step 3 of zpanel x installation was a loop. After disableing apparmor I restarted and was asked to repeat the step. I did this three times and quit.

Comment: oh yeah check out ipconfig3, and there are at least 3 other choices at sourceforge